# Query Problem - Result Coming incorrect

Tags: sql, mysql

I am having trouble solving this. Please help.

I have a table named Product_Information.  I want to count the number of products present in a category and subcategory.

This is the table

```
Product_Id - Product_Title - Product_Sub_Category - Product_Category 
1 ----------------abc------------------XYX------------------X
2 ----------------def------------------XYX------------------Z
3 ----------------ghi------------------XYX------------------X
4 ----------------jkl------------------XYM------------------Z
```

and I want the result to be like

```
result 
------

Product_Category-Product_Sub_Category-count(Product_Id) 
X--------------------XYX-------------------------2
Z--------------------XYX-------------------------1
Z--------------------XYM-------------------------1
```

(Sorry for presenting information in a bad way)

I used the following Query:

```
Select
Product_Category,
Product_Sub_Category,
count(`Product_Id`)
from product_information 
group by 
Product_Category
```

but it's giving me wrong result.

Comment: Can you edit your question and present it better?

Comment: Specifically, can you put your table and queries in a code block.

Comment: don't you need to `group by Product_Category, Product_Sub_Category`, you only `group by Product_Category` in the code in your question

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the number of products in a specific subcategory then use:

```
select count(*) from Product_Information 
where Product_Category = ? and Product_Sub_Category = ?
```

If you need the numbers for all of them, then you will need to group like so:

```
select Product_Category, Product_Sub_Category, count(*) 
from Product_Information 
group by Product_Category, Product_Sub_Category;
```

Comment: Problem is that if i use the Query 2, i get a mixed result. 
mean i see the sub category which is not present in a category.. kindly help

Answer (score 1):

You can either use an analytic function and partition by, or you can just do a couple queries separately (which can be combined in one large query if you prefer), but here are the basic queries:
**Count by category**:

```
Product_Category, count(Product_Id)

from product_information

group by Product_Category
```

**Count by sub category**:

```
Product_Category, Product_Sub_Category, count(Product_Id)

from product_information

group by Product_Category, Product_Sub_Category
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your  Query: Select

```
 
Product_Category, Product_Sub_Category, count(Product_Id)

from product_information

group by Product_Category , Product_Sub_Category ;
```

It will give you result fine.